# Search database table for the value entered in textbox and display the search results in dropdown list with ASP.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, search

I want to search database for the value entered in the textbox.
And display the results which match the value in dropdownlist.

Scenario:

1. My database table contain list of injuries,diseases
2. If I type in the textbox injury and click the search button., it has to search the database table for injuries and bind the list of injuries to the dropdown list.

any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show some efforts from your side. People are not here to do your work

Comment: You better have a look at [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) about how to ask question

Comment: On button click:1)Create Connection object,Open connection2)Create Command object and fire query like:"Select columnname(injury) from tablename where injury like 'value entered in textbox %'" and you are done

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this you can either use jquery and web service to do this and you can also use autocomplete extender to acheive this.

Regards